# Find out which version to install Cocoapods

Tags: ios, dependency-management, cocoapods

How and where can i found out which version of the frameworks is preferred to install via cocoapods for different iOS sdks?[some times it shows error incompatible version used]

For example I want to install Restkit.Which will be the statement i need to add in the pod as version number.How it can be identified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have a look at their pod specification (e.g. [pod spec for RestKit 0.20.0pre2](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/RestKit/0.20.0pre2/RestKit.podspec)). There are a couple of lines stating which platform this is based on

```
# Platform setup
s.requires_arc = true
s.ios.deployment_target = '5.0'
s.osx.deployment_target = '10.7'
```

So if you want to use RestKit 0.20.0pre2 in your project, you want to use the same settings as a minimum.

Comment: Thanks,I am developing for iOS 6 and above so can I use this version??